# TextField Input Accessory View Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, inputaccessoryview

i'm adding view above keyboard, for this i'm using textfield input accessoryView. 
i'm adding this using following code but its application get crash once i make textfield first responder. can anyone let me know what i'm doing wrong. other thing i need to point out if i simply put this view in my controller its working fine but for component based approach once i try to give this view class it fails.

```
  keyboardView = (KeyboardAccessoryView*)[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"KeyboardAccessoryView" owner:self options:nil];
    self.secureNumberTxtField.inputAccessoryView = keyboardView;
    self.secureNumberTxtField.delegate = self;

    [self.secureNumberTxtField becomeFirstResponder];
```

**error:**
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM tag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: `loadNibNamed:` returns an array which your view is probably the first object of.

Comment: (KeyboardAccessoryView*)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"KeyboardAccessoryView" owner:self options:nil]firstObject]

Comment: thankyou so much @dan and Teja . yes its working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
keyboardView = (KeyboardAccessoryView*)[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"KeyboardAccessoryView" owner:self options:nil];
```

with

```
 keyboardView = (KeyboardAccessoryView*)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"KeyboardAccessoryView" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
```

that returns an array which is not a KeyboardAccessoryView and can lead to a crash